# Avoid app pool restart asp classic iis6 and iis7 for text change

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, iis-6

I have a classic asp application running on both iis-6 and iis-7 at the same time

It load balanced between iis-6 and iis-7 (Horrendously Poor set-up I know)

I have been asked to make a small text change to the application.
On an .asp page

If the app pool restarts the application takes a little while to restart. More than I can specify as a change window

I am aware of the numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart which defaults to 20.
Is their a way to determine what number this is currently at?

And does operate uniformly between iis6 and iis7

Or is their a better way to manage text changes?

Comment: `CompilationSection.NumRecompilesBeforeAppRestart` only applied to ASP.NET, not classic ASP. If you're running classic, then you can make a change at any time. It isn't compiled.

Comment: @Seamus Thankyou. i will give it a go :)

Comment: @Seamus you okay to copy your comment to an answer so i can mark it as correct?

Comment: OK, I added it. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CompilationSection.NumRecompilesBeforeAppRestart` only applied to ASP.NET, not classic ASP. If you're running classic, then you can make a change at any time. It isn't compiled.